# What's the difference between the Brush and Pencil tools?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush

I don't frequently use either - I'm a pen tool guy. (which may explain my lack of knowledge in them), but what is the actual functional difference between them?

Paintbrush Tool <kbd>B</kbd>
[image: brush tool]

Pencil Tool <kbd>N</kbd>
[image: pencil tool]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a whole lot other than the brush automatically applying a brush appearance.

- You *can't* use the Brush Tool unless you *first* choose a brush to apply to the path.
- You *can't* apply a brush appearance to a Pencil Tool path until *after* it's been drawn.

I can't remember exactly, but I believe the Brush tool came first. Then Adobe merely removed the auto-brush application and there's the Pencil Tool. Other than this functionality, there's really no difference. In fact, double-click them in the tool bar... same options.

Adobe often does this to make it *seem* as if there's some new feature, when really it's only a different presentation for *existing* functionality options. I.E.:

- The Blob Brush Tool - Just a Brush with a calligraphic appearance set then expanded.
- The Bounding Box - Just the Free Transform tool with a few options removed.
- The Scissor Tool - Just the Knife Tool with only a click rather than a  drag
- The Shape Builder Tool - Just Pathfinder operations

It's these features that may make working faster or easier, but they don't offer anything unique in themselves.

Comment: Brushtool is pressure sensitive. Anyway Shape Builder does things pathfinder does not do.

Comment: The pressure sensitivity of the Brush tool would be part of the brush appearance in my opinion. Not an inherent ability of the tool. And Shape Builder is pathfinder math.. just localized.

Comment: yeah but the pen tool does not record pressure curves. And shape builder while localized does know how to delete paths that are open ended. But yeah i agree theres no inherent reason why adobe needs so many different tools. Especially since most of them are botched. There's no need for rounded rectangle tool, star tool is way too specialized. Cut and knife could be options of one tool as could shape builder and live paint bucket. The arc and spiral tools are nearly useless as is the free transform tool and so on

Comment: Gong to have to disagree about the Free Transform. **It's** the useful one... I *constantly* use the Free Transform Tool in everything I create. the Bounding box is the useless version :)

Comment: theres really no reason why the black selection arrow couldn't do what free transform does though. Either one of those is extra. I would just roll the two into one.

Comment: Oh sure there is.. that freakin' Bounding Box is *in the way* 99% of the time. It's completely unnecessary. The Bounding Box as added to CS4 to make CorelDraw users more comfortable, that's the ONLY reason it's there. It never existed prior to CS4, because its NOT needed.