# What is the difference between the pencil tool, the pen tool, and the brush tool in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush, pen-tool, pencil

Is there any difference between the three besides that the brush and pencil are much more flexible than the pen?

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - Please look through [tour] to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. Then look over [ask] and [answer] a question to see what makes a good query here, and how best to frame it. As initially posted, your query was automatically flagged by the system as low-quality, due primarily to the length - also worth noting this is both easily searchable info and classically tech-support too - so your question might get flagged to close. Perhaps you could edit it to better fit our guidelines. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pen tool - Precise placement of anchors and control over curves

Pencil Tool - Freeform creation of disjointed paths.

Brush Tool - Freeform creation of disjointed paths with automatic application of brush appearance

Blob Brush Tool - Freeform creation of a brush path suing a calligraphic brush which will auto-expand when the cursor is lifted, leaving a shape rather than a stroked path

---

There are not vast, major difference on the whole. You can use the Pen Tool to draw a path and then apply a brush stroke to that path.. so...

It's not designed to be "one tool for one specific task". It's merely a set of tools to allow the user to draw/create in the manner *they* feel most comfortable with or the way they feel is most useful.

---

**Highly** related: [What's the difference between the Brush and Pencil tools?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/104679/whats-the-difference-between-the-brush-and-pencil-tools)